# How to blur webcam background in Microsoft Teams

Tags: images, camera, image-manipulation, microsoft-teams

I am currently using Teams for a master and I would like to blur my backgrounds, do you know any way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam
https://github.com/allo-/virtual_webcam_background

Comment: @IporSircer - any successful story with these tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft Teams has this option built-in ([as described in the official Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780)). Unfortunately, the documentation also states that as of today:

> Notes:
>
> - For now, Linux users aren't able to use this feature.
> - Background effects won't be available to you if you're using Teams through optimized virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI).

So unfortunately, until Microsoft Teams is updated for Linux, if you want to use this feature, you need to either try your luck with a Wine version or pass your camera stream through an external filtering tool (such as [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)).

Comment: OBS doesn't blur

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with OBS or its features - a friend of mine used it to substitute a green blanket used as a background in his webcam with an image and then plugged it into Teams, that's how I know it could be done. I haven't used it personally, so I can't help you much with that. For effects such as blur, you'd probably have to use the StreamFX OBS plugin.

Comment: You can upvote this feature to the Teams development team: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e39e0921-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this to control my webcam and background on any video call app on Linux

https://github.com/hamidzr/webcam-mods

Included Mods
Face Tracking
Set up your webcam to focus and follow your face by cropping and resizing the frames it receives from your main webcam.

Person Segmentation
Separate the people in the frame from the background using a fast real-time prediction model. The model outputs a mask values between 0 to 1. We have mods based on this to swap the background with:

a solid color
another image
blurred version of the input frame (aka blur my background)
Cropping
Interactively move your camera around with arrow keys ctrl+arrowkeys Resize the cropped frame using ctrl+shift+arrowkeys

Padding
Interactively pad your camera output with arrow keys alt+arrowkeys while keeping the output framesize fixed.

Comment: So this tool seems to be related to you perhaps.  Is it relevant to MS Teams at all ?  How is it relevant to the OPs question?

Comment: I'm assuming OP is on Linux and AFAIK neither MS Teams nor Zoom support background blurring, at least without a green screen, thus the OP could use something like this and a virtual webcam device to not have to rely on MS teams to add this feature and achieve what they want to do right now on Teams as well as any other video calling software on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Some people propose to use FakeCam, but I could not make it work, it seems Teams prevents from using Virtual Devices...
More info about that solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298699/ms-teams-sharescreen-and-blur-background-features/1298704#1298704

But I just found this: https://gitlab.com/parrot_parrot/ms-teams-replace-background

I tested it, but I am having problems installing one of its requirements, tensorflow_gpu==1.15.3 ... I have a Python version superior to the one specified here, maybe that has something do to with it.

Still, think of this as a starting point for other's experiments, I will update this comment if I fix and make it work

Answer (score 0):

Now web version has this feature available without any plugins, additional apps! Just use chrome under linux and log in to https://teams.microsoft.com.

Comment: It's a shame that this is still not implemented in the linux desktop version...

Comment: Has the feature been removed from the web version or am I missing something?